# TortoiseGit shows up an error done in Git bash

Tags: github, git-bash, tortoisegit, git

Every time I try to do something with TortoiseGit, Git Command Progress shows this error. Some days ago I was trying to use Git Bash and I typed 'git credential-'. From that day, this always shows up. 
How can i fix/remove this?

[Here is the screen of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktLbo.png)

edit: yet tried to reinstall both Git and TortoiseGit. It shows up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to solve it:
in `TortoiseGit -> Settings1 -->`Git -> Credential` there was an Helper, probably set in a wrong way. Removing it fixed that issue.